# Error in C code using Structure

Tags: c

i'm currently working on an assignment on which i have to use structure is c to WAP to take input of 100 employees as name, age and salary and show it as output but I am having some error which im not able to fix.

PS: Newbie.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 100


struct employee
{
    int empno;
    char name[100];
    int age, salary;
} e[100];

int main(void)
{ 
    struct employee emp[100]
    int i, n;
    clrscr();

        printf("Enter the number of employees\n");
        scanf("%d",&n);
            for (i=0;i<n;i++)
                {
                    printf("\n Enter employee number : ");
                    scanf("%d",&e[i].empno);
                    printf("\n Enter name of employee : ");
                    scanf("%s",&e[i].name);
                    printf("\n Enter age of employee : ");
                    scanf("%d",&e[i].age);
                    printf("\n Enter salary of employee : ");
                    scanf("%d",&e[i].salary);
                }   
        printf("\n Emp. No. Name \t Age \t Salary \n\n");
            for (i=0;i<n;i++)
                printf("%d \t %s \t %d \%d \n", 
e[i].empno,e[i].name,e[i].age,e[i].salary);
return 0;
}
```

and this is the error

```
prog.c: In function ‘main’:
prog.c:15:9: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘int’
         int i, n;
         ^~~
prog.c:16:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘clrscr’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         clrscr();
         ^~~~~~
prog.c:25:33: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[100]’ [-Wformat=]
                         scanf("%s",&e[i].name);
                             ^
```

Comment: Care to be more specific than "some error"?

Comment: this: prog.c: In function ‘main’:
prog.c:15:9: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘int’
         int i, n;
         ^~~
prog.c:16:9: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘clrscr’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         clrscr();
         ^~~~~~
prog.c:25:33: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[100]’ [-Wformat=]
                         scanf("%s",&e[i].name);
                                 ^

Comment: *having some error* is an absolutely useless problem description. We can't see your screen or read your mind. Explain **specifically** what *error* or problem you're having, and ask a **specific question** about that problem. Do so by making an [edit] to your question and adding the details there in the question where they belong, not buried in comment noise.

Comment: 1) `struct employee emp[100]` --> `struct employee emp[100];` or delete this.

Comment: edit the thread, added the error in bottom. Thanks

Comment: 2) `\%d` --> `\\%d`

Comment: 3) `&e[i].name` --> `e[i].name`

Comment: 4) `clrscr();` : Delete this. This is not standard function.

Comment: The error messages are really clear about what's wrong. Can you ask about specifically what you don't understand?

Comment: In the error, i am not understanding the part where it says "expected "=" ... before int.

Comment: Problem fixed, thanks!

Comment: _"expected "=" ... before int._ You forgot to write `;` at the end of the previous line.

Answer (score 4):

1. Remove `clrscr` function
2. Remove `e[100]`
3. Add `;` after `emp[100]`
4. Fix indentation
5. Use `emp` instead of `e` everywhere.
6. Use `SIZE` and add `MAX_STR_LEN`.
7. Change `\%d` to `\t %d`
8. Separate `age` and `salary` to two lines (best practice).
9. Check input `n`.
10. Should also add some overflow protection when getting names of employees. I leave that for you to research.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_STR_LEN 100
#define SIZE 100


struct employee
{
    int empno;
    char name[MAX_STR_LEN];
    int age;
    int salary;
};

int main(void)
{ 
    struct employee emp[SIZE];
    int i, n;

    printf("Enter the number of employees\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    if (n > SIZE) {
        printf("Too many employees (will process first %d)\n", SIZE);
        n = SIZE;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("\n Enter employee number : ");
        scanf("%d",&emp[i].empno);

        printf("\n Enter name of employee : ");
        scanf("%s",&emp[i].name);

        printf("\n Enter age of employee : ");
        scanf("%d",&emp[i].age);

        printf("\n Enter salary of employee : ");
        scanf("%d",&emp[i].salary);
    }   
    printf("\n Emp. No. Name \t Age \t Salary \n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d \t %s \t %d \t %d \n", 
            emp[i].empno, emp[i].name, emp[i].age, emp[i].salary);
    }
    return 0;
}
```